# Lotus Java proxy in time read order

Tags: java

I made a lotus Java proxy, but the mailbox list was not arranged in chronological order, what should I do。

```
Database database = session.getDatabase(session.getServerName, string, false);
View view = database.getView("($Inbox)");
Document document = view.getFirstDocument();
.....
```

My idea is to use the search function to get the time - arranged mailing list. How should the code write?

Answer (score 0):

By the way, getting the time - arranged mailing list also needs to be the inbox or the hair box...